# How to user 'Geolocator.distanceBetween' with variables from a state Provider

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, flutter-provider, geolocator

I am developing a salon directory app. The location of the user will be acquired and used alonside the location of the salon (from Firebase Database) to calculate the distance to the salon for each user. When the user signs up Location permission is requested this is (supposed to be) stored in the userDetailModel and provider to manage the state across the whole app.

The issue I am facing is that even though the user latitude and longitude is acquired (can see it when I do print in the sign up screen) it does not seem to be picked up in the popularSalonWidget (within the home page). This widget needs the values to calculate the distance and to display it. The salon location (lat and lng) is working fine.

--  UPDATE --
The code calculation actually works as expected, so I can get the userLat and userLng when I create a new user (flow from the sign up screen). But if I reload the app, or direct to a new page in the app and then go back the user location data is lost and the widget disappears which I am assuming is due to this in the popular salon widget block

> ```
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     UserDetailsModel userDetails =
>         Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context).userDetails;
>     if (salons.isEmpty) {
>       return const Center(
>         child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
>       );
> ```

```
class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _determinePosition();
  }

  Position? position;
  String userLocation = '';
  late final Salon? salon;

  Future<void> _determinePosition() async {
    try {
      bool serviceEnabled;
      LocationPermission permission;

      serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
      if (!serviceEnabled) {
        throw Exception('Location services are disabled.');
      }

      permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
          throw Exception('Location permissions are denied');
        }
      }

      if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
        throw Exception(
            'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
      }

      Position newPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      );
      setState(() {
        position = newPosition;
      });
      _updateUserDetails(position);
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error determining position: $error');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateUserDetails(Position? position) async {
    if (position != null) {
      List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude,
        position.longitude,
      );

      Placemark place = placemark[0];
      cityController.text = '${place.street}, ${place.locality}';
      double userLat = position.latitude;
      double userLng = position.longitude;

      // Update user details using Provider
      Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateUserCity('${place.street}, ${place.locality}');
      Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateUserLat(userLat);
      Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .updateUserLng(userLng);
      print(userLng); //works as expected
      print(userLat); //works as expected 
    }
  } 

class PopularSalonswidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Salon? salon;
  final Function(int) onNoOfReviewUpdated;
  const PopularSalonswidget({
    Key? key,
    this.salon,
    required this.onNoOfReviewUpdated,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PopularSalonswidget> createState() => _PopularSalonswidgetState();
}

class _PopularSalonswidgetState extends State<PopularSalonswidget> {
  final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  List<Salon> salons = [];
  late UserDetailsModel userDetails;
  Map<String, double> salonDistances = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userDetails =
        Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false).userDetails;
    if (userDetails.userLat != null && userDetails.userLng != null) {
      _fetchSalons();
    }
  }

  void _fetchSalons() {
    db.collection('salons').get().then((snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        salons =
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Salon.fromJson(doc.data())).toList();
        for (var salon in salons) {
          final calculatedDistance = calculateDistance(
            userDetails.userLat!,
            userDetails.userLng!,
            salon.latitude,
            salon.longitude,
          );
          print(userDetails.userLat); //getting 0.0
          print(userDetails.userLng); //getting 0.0
          print(salon.latitude); //works as expected 
          salonDistances[salon.id] = calculatedDistance;
          print(calculatedDistance);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final newDetails =
        Provider.of<UserDetailsProvider>(context, listen: false).userDetails;
    if (newDetails != null && newDetails != userDetails) {
      userDetails = newDetails;
      if (userDetails.userLat != null && userDetails.userLng != null) {
        _fetchSalons();
      }
    }
  }
  Stream<int> _getReviewCountStream(String salonId) {
    return db
        .collection('salons')
        .doc(salonId)
        .collection('reviews')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.length);
  }

//this is my calculator method 
double calculateDistance(
    double userLat, double userLng, double salonLat, double salonLng) {
  return Geolocator.distanceBetween(userLat, userLng, salonLat, salonLng);
}
```